# Is the field inside a conducting sphere always zero?

Tags: electrostatics

If somehow, we manage to remove the valence electrons of all the atoms in a conducting sphere, so that all that remains in it, are positively charged ions, will the charge still, get distributed only on the surface, and the field inside  it still be zero?

I saw quite a few similar questions like the one i asked above, but most of the answers were explaining how the charge is uniformly spread over the surface due to repulsive forces, and talked about the Gauss law (which i haven't studied yet in my course) but no one seemed to tackle this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

If the material is an ideal insulator then the sphere will remain in this state where no redistribution of charge takes place.
If the material is metallic(conducting) then removing valence electrons from individual atoms does not make sense. According to the electron sea model however, removing n electrons from the sphere will make charge accumulate on the surface.
We must consider that no material is ideally conducting or insulating, therefore, neither of the above models accurately define a real system. But depending upon how large n(number of electrons) is and conductivity of the material, an outer layer of charge will accumulate whose thickness will vary upon the above factors. My understanding is that as n increases and as conductivity decreases, this thickness will increase.

Comment: what if the thickness is almost tending to the radius of the metallic sphere,i.e. not all the electrons are successfully removed, then will there be an electric field inside the sphere?

Comment: Yes, according to me, a certain region inside the sphere will have non zero electric field.

Comment: Although, according to my textbook, they've clearly mentioned that,"In a conducting metal sphere, the charges will always be distributed over the surface, and no field lines will exist inside it" that's what was quite perplexing to me. can you help me out if its valid or incorrect?

Comment: Almost all physics textbooks assume the ideal case and for the ideal case, the statement is correct. You may refer to Resnick and Halliday's textbook, it has a simple proof of this statement.

Comment: Do you know how big would be the charge on a sphere, if you remove all the electrons, the Voltage would be extreme, so you would have a huge discharge .
you can  not take all of then away, or do you have a way to do it.? so the question is not one which belongs to physic